# Hidden DIV position

Tags: html, css

I have some forms, which are in some DIVs. DIVs are hidden, and are shown when you select an option from select box. I need a way to position the hidden DIVs, because the default position is under the forementioned select box.

Comment: show us the demo please......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table> 
<tr>
<td>
<select id = "opts" onchange = "showForm()">
<option value = "0">Select Option</option>
<option value = "1">Option 1</option>
<option value = "2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<div id = "f1" style="display:none">
<form name= "form1">
Content of Form 1
</form>
</div>

<div id = "f2" style="display:none">
<form name= "form2">
Content of Form 2
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function showForm(){
var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;
if (selopt == 1) {
document.getElementById("f1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("f2").style.display="none";
}
if (selopt == 2) {
document.getElementById("f2").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("f1").style.display="none";
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Here is the preview http://jsbin.com/eworah/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Thanks alot, but how could forms be formatted, each form should be on the same place?

Comment: @user1481792 Could you give all or some of your forms codes?

Comment: @user1481792 I cant't understand What you exactly want. please give more information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use Z-index to position the  elements above the select box. It would be nice to see a demo first though

Comment: Here's the sample code: http://pastebin.com/TXexiiqF

I want the forms to be on the right side of the select box, not under it. Sorry if it's a newb question, but hey, I'm a newb to this =)

Answer (score 0):

try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jUUuy/1/). it may help you.
just pick the idea and use along with your Select Options.
**here is jquery:**

```
$('#testDiv').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.hoveruserinfo').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#testDiv').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.hoveruserinfo').fadeOut();
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.hoveruserinfo
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="testDiv">  
Test
</div>
<div class="hoveruserinfo" style="position:absolute;width:206px;display:none;margin-left:147px;">
James Smith <span>this is my data</span>           
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @TheifMaster...done with the code too.